# Handle google date strings and increment them

Tags: java, string, parsing, date

I am using the google analytics api and it needs strings of dates (i.e. "2013-03-01") for start and end dates.

I will run queries in a loop where it pools each day and then increments it (i.e. start date in round 1 is "2013-03-01" and end date is the same, then in the second round the date is "2013-03-02").

Now the question is how can I have the string change to that? I was thinking some ubercomplicated way of using `charAt()` and checking if it is <30 and then convert it to a int, +1 and then `toString()` it again.

is there an easier way?

Comment: BTW, the "ccyy-mm-dd" date format is called [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ParseException {
    final String dateString = "2013-03-01";
    final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(c.getTime()));
}
```